# How to return a template from a function without the request argument?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am not sure if this makes any sense but I am trying to figure out a way to get a function without request argument to return an HTML template. The code below will help you better understand my point.

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    global running, row_count, thread
    if request.method == 'POST':
        row_count = 0
        thread = threading.Thread(target=fun)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        running = True
        return render(request, 'scraper/home.html', {'countries': countries, 'running': running})
    else:
        return render(request, 'scraper/home.html')

def fun():
    global row_count, finished, thread
    while True:
        row_count += 5
        if row_count == 15:
            finished = True
            thread.join()
            return
        time.sleep(5)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to reflect that `finished=True`in my `'scraper/home.html/` template. I want to make an element in my template based on the value of `finished`. Something like this:

**scraper/home.html**

```
{% if finished %}
    <p>Finished!</p>
{% endif %}
```

I'll appreciate your help on this. Thanks

Comment: You would need some JS/AJAX on your page to poll the status of an asynchronous task. You may find something like celery useful for running asynchronous tasks http://www.celeryproject.org/

Comment: I already got it to work using AJAX. Thanks!